# How does one debug PHP in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: manual-testing

When a PHP error occurs in jQuery Mobile, jQuery Mobile issues a popup box that reads "Page Error."

This is great, but not conducive to debugging because I can't see what the error is. How can I see the PHP error in jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Welcome to SQA, David.  Are you asking, "How do I use jQuery Mobile to see the PHP error?", or "How do I see the PHP error that jQuery Mobile encountered?"

Comment: Thanks, how do I see the PHP error that jQuery Mobile encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Check the log

Typically, all php errors are logged. The location of the log depends on your operating system. For example, on Ubuntu and Mac OS the log is located at `/var/log/php/errors.log`.
So, in a terminal just `tail /var/log/php/errors.log` to see the latest errors.

You can find out where your log is and change the location of the log by searching your php.ini file for `error_log` option. Here is a tutorial on how to do this on unix-like systems: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html

Comment: Thank you, I can see the errors in /var/log/php/errors.log.